# iPython does not read ~/.inputrc

Tags: python, macos, ipython, readline

I am using iPython. The docs says that I should be able to remap the readline library's keys using inputrc. Here is what I have in my inputrc:

```
set editing-mode emacs
set keymap emacs
Meta-h: backward-word
Meta-s: forward-word
Control-h: backward-char
Control-s: forward-char
Control-n: previous-history
Control-t: next-history
Control-p: yank
Meta-p: yank-pop
```

These mappings simply do not work when I load iPython. I'm on OS X 10.9 Mavericks. I do not see any warnings that libedit is being used instead of readline. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe call IPython from inside Emacs? There should be ways to set these keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [IPython Documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.2.0/interactive/reference.html#customizing-readline-behavior):

> All these features are based on the GNU readline library, which has an extremely customizable interface. Normally, readline is configured via a file which defines the behavior of the library; the details of the syntax for this can be found in the readline documentation available with your system or on the Internet. IPython doesn’t read this file (if it exists) directly, but it does support passing to readline valid options via a simple interface. In brief, you can customize readline by setting the following options in your configuration file (note that these options can not be specified at the command line):
>
> readline_parse_and_bind: this holds a list of strings to be executed via a readline.parse_and_bind() command. The syntax for valid commands of this kind can be found by reading the documentation for the GNU readline library, as these commands are of the kind which readline accepts in its configuration file.
>
> readline_remove_delims: a string of characters to be removed from the default word-delimiters list used by readline, so that completions may be performed on strings which contain them. Do not change the default value unless you know what you’re doing.

So, you have to set `readline_parse_and_bind` in the configuration file (by default, this is in `/path/to/ipython/dir/profile_default/ipython_config`. You can generate the default config with an example using `ipython profile create`.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I fail to solve the issue this way.

Comment: @AlfredM. I answered this three years ago and IPython has evolved significantly since, so I'm no longer confident in my original answer. Will post an update soon.

Answer (score 1):

The method I found was to create a new IPython profile with the
vi-keys option enabled.

- [Source: Options Reference](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html)
- [Source: Managing Profiles](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html)

### Set your keybinding mode to vi:

Generate blank config file:

```
ipython profile create [profile-name]
```

Running the command should show the path of the generated profiles,
which are python (.py) files.

From: [Source: Options Reference](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#autoindent)

> Starting with 5.0, IPython uses prompt_toolkit in place of readline,
> it thus can recognize lines ending in ‘:’ and indent the next line,
> while also un-indenting automatically after ‘raise’ or ‘return’, and
> support real multi-line editing as well as syntactic coloration
> during edition.
>
> This feature does not use the readline library anymore, so it will
> not honor your ~/.inputrc configuration (or whatever file your
> INPUTRC environment variable points to).
>
> **In particular if you want to change the input mode to vi, you will
> need to set the `TerminalInteractiveShell.editing_mode` configuration
> option of IPython.**

(emphasis mine)

So, navigate to the `ipython_config.py` file, and make sure the
following lines are in it:

```
c = get_config()
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.editing_mode = 'vi'
```

### Start IPython with a particular profile:

[Source: Managing Profiles](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html#profiles)

At a terminal, type in the following command (don't type the braces
literally, they're just a placeholder for the actual name of the
profile).

`$> ipython --profile={profile-name}`