# IPython, restore cursor line position from history

Tags: python, cursor, ipython, history, read-eval-print-loop

I'm playing with [pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing) in IPython REPL in **terminal** (not web). The statement I'm currently working with is:

```
In [83]: (pp.Literal('-') + pp.Word(pp.alphanums + '-')).parseString('-x-x x-x', parseAll=True)
```

Now I'm playing with the beginning of this statement and every time I execute it, and then go back one line in history (via `Up` arrow), the cursor ends up being at the end of the line, so now I have to go back to the place I left last time I executed it with arrows or `Ctrl-B`/`Alt-B`.

That's very inconvenient when I'm doing it many times in a row as I'm trying different things at the same place. Can I make IPython REPL jump in history with cursor position in line restored?

---

EDIT: I've just learned that you can get this feature in readline (and hence in Bash too) by adding  the following to `~/.inputrc`:

```
set history-preserve-point
```

IPython seems to not use readline anymore according to latest answer in [iPython does not read ~/.inputrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793051/ipython-does-not-read-inputrc), but perhaps there's a way to tune prompt_toolkit appropriately.

However, Python REPL uses readline!